# Rails 4 active admin heroku superclass mismatch for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, activeadmin

I used active admin gem for admin dashboard and I deployed it to Heroku then got an error like this **superclass mismatch for class BuyersController (TypeError)**.it works well in local.it was happened only on Heroku server.

The buyer file

**The first line was error occur**

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Buyer do
     ---code here---
 end
```

Gemfile

```
 gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

Comment: Does it happen when you start your app local in production mode?

Comment: Please post all code lines with contains `BuyersController` in your App.

Comment: Such errors can occur if you haven't committed your latest changes or new files to branch you pushed to Heroku master.  This should probably be closed as it would need at least the #controllers message from buyers.rb to be a complete question